# Are 4-dimensional mapping tori always spin?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

We know that all compact orientable manifolds of dimension 3 are spin. In 4 dimensions, $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is not spin. I would like to ask if all 4-dimensional compact orientable mapping tori are spin?

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "orientable mapping tori"? Do you presume you have a map $f:A\rightarrow A$? If so then the mapping tori would be depend on $f$ as well, not just $A$. And by 4 dimensional you mean $A$ is 4 dimensional, or the mapping tori is 4 dimensional?

Comment: A mapping torus is a fiber bundle over $S^1$ (the base manifold). A mapping torus is orientable if the fiber bundle is orientable

Comment: I see. So the fiber must be 3 dimensional.

Comment: Yes, the fiber is 3 dimensional

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165561/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Ryan Budney below.

> The answer is no.  As was described in the thread: [Spin structure on mapping torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72766/spin-structure-on-mapping-torus), a mapping torus has a spin structure if and only if the monodromy of the bundle (over $S^1$) fixes a spin structure.  The mapping torus I'm going to describe is a bundle over $S^1$ with fibre $S^1 \times S^2$.
>
> The mapping class group of $S^1 \times S^2$ is of order $8$.  If you pass to the subgroup that preserves the fundamental classes of the factors, you get a subgroup of order $2$, the generator can be thought of as the diffeomorphism that twists the $S^2$ factor by $2 \pi$ as one walks around the circle factor.
>
> This automorphism does not preserve any spin structure on $S^1 \times S^2$, it acts as an involution on the spin structures, with no fixed spin structures.